# background run timer swift

Tags: swift, timer

I want the timer to run even when I close the application. I want it to work in the background counter. the timer goes back one second when I run it.(counter) How can I do that?

```
class TimerViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedDay: String?

    var seconds = 
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        sliderOutlet.isHidden = true
        startOutlet.isHidden = true
    }

    @objc func counter() {

        seconds -= 1
        favoriteDayTextField.text = String(seconds) + " Seconds"
        var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: seconds)
        bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        })

        if (seconds == 0) {
            timer.invalidate()

            if self.button.isOn {
               updateState()
            } else {
               updateState1()
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find all answers [in the iOS documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)  Then, I advise you to pay attention to code formatting; for yourself, but especially when asking for help here.

Comment: Can you tell the use case and we can help you with how to achieve that..

Comment: I want the counter to continue working even after turning off the application while the counter is running. @KeshavRaj

Comment: @BerkEylen Checkout the answer and tell me if you want to achieve the same and I am understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear what you want to achieve. Suppose you want to update the label after the timer has started each 1 second. Then one approach will be:-

1. Start the timer in view did load if the duration is remaining.
2. Register for applicationWillTerminate
3. In application will terminate save the passed duration and terminated time to calculate remaining time in next launch.

   ```
   var remainingDuration: TimeInterval!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let remainingDurationFromLastLaunch = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "duration") as? TimeInterval ?? 0
    let lastTerminatedTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastTerminatedDate") as? Date ?? Date()

   if Date().timeInterval(since: lastTerminatedTime) > remainingDurationFromLastLaunch {

     remainingDuration = remainingDurationFromLastLaunch - Date().timeInterval(since: lastTerminatedTime)
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TimerViewController.applicationWillTerminate), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)

   } else { //Duration is passed....Do whatever you want

    }
   }

   @objc func counter() {

   remainingDuration -= 1
   if remainingDuration == 0 { //Duration is passed....Do whatever you want
      timer.invalidate()
      timer = nil
    } else {
      favoriteDayTextField.text = String(remainingDuration) + " Seconds"
   }
   }

   @objc func applicationWillTerminate() {
      if timer != nil {
      backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
       UserDefaults.standard.set(remainingDuration, forKey: "duration")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastTerminatedDate")

       }
       self?.endBackgroundTask()
      }
     }

   func endBackgroundTask() {
   UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
   backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The only way for your *iOS application* to perform *some action* even while it is in the *background* is to use `Background Modes` .

[image: Background modes as shown in Xcode]

> However you cannot perform anything and everything while your
>   *application is in background*

There are certain limitations to the type of tasks that you can perform . I have attached a really good article for your reference

[Background Modes Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

However, I am *not sure* if you can initiate and continue a timer *sort of functionality* while your application is in background

*Though, keep in mind* , once your application is closed (i.e. by double tapping the home button and swiping the application window up to close it completely) , not even Background modes work at that point because the user does not want to run your app anymore, *even in the background*

Comment: Thank you for helping. That article is not very revealing

Comment: See, there are limitation to _what you can do in the background_ while working with iOS, to provide user with better experience and conserve battery as well . You might have to work some workaround if you want to achieve what you are trying to achieve (as there are only 9 `Background Modes` available currently)